# Visual Studio 2019 - многопроцессорная отладка

Tags: visual-studio

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в Visual Studio 2019 включить многопроцессорную отладку.

А то, получается так - я устанавливаю точку остановки на сточке кода, но она туда никогда не попадает, потому что этот код вызывается в другом процессе относительно основного процесса запуска.

Comment: Для отладки подключитесь к нужному процессу после его запуска. Или вставьте в код нужного процессора вызов отладчика.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, ох, а примерно, где это подключение к нужному процессу делается ? Не разу до этого с процессами не работал.

Comment: [Debug multiple processes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-multiple-processes?view=vs-2019)